# gnuplot trasparent gradient background

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to have a transparent gradient backgroud in gnuplot. In my script I have some arrows. But, the problem is that when I have a background the arrows are not displayed. Here is the code without background:

```
set arrow from x1_l, 0 to x1_l, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set arrow from x1_r, 0 to x1_r, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red'

plot  "..\\Points.txt" using 1:2 t "Point" lc rgb "blue"
```

Here is the output:
[Plot without background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpvP5.png)

When I add the background (I need a gradient background) with the following code, the arrow is disappeared.

```
set table 'shadowkey.dat'
splot [xl:xh] [yl:yh] x/(xh-xl)
unset table

set arrow from x1_l, 0 to x1_l, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set arrow from x1_r, 0 to x1_r, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red'

unset colorbox
set palette defined (0 "#8888ff", 1 "#ffffff")
plot [0.8:0.95] [0:1] 'shadowkey.dat' w ima, \
"\\Points.txt" using 1:2 t "Point" lc rgb "blue"
```

**Moreover, I want to have a plot where the gradient background will be with two red lines. How can I do that?**

Example: 
[Background in a region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQwa.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use the `front` keyword:

```
set arrow from x1_l, 0 to x1_l, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red' front
set arrow from x1_r, 0 to x1_r, 1.0 nohead lc rgb 'red' front

set object 1 rectangle from x1_l, 0 to x1_r, 1.0 fc rgb "cyan" fs solid 1.0 front
```

to get the gradient just inside the lines:

```
set table 'shadowkey.dat'
splot [x1_l:x1_r] [0:1] x/(xh-xl)
unset table
```

maybe better to leave a space between the lines and the gradient:

```
set table 'shadowkey.dat'
my_val=(x1_r-x1_l)/20
splot [x1_l+my_val:x1_r-my_val] [0:1] x/(xh-xl)
unset table
```

[Here you can find an alternative way to create gradients](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.fr/2011_08_01_archive.html)

Comment: Thanks. can u please ans the bold question

Comment: I need gradient fill style.